# How to export reports from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to export data like when builds where done and when release where done. I do see them when I click on the build section or In Release section. But I am not able to export this data for further analysis. Is there a way to export this?

Comment: You can find all possible ways from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/?view=vsts#pivot=index&panel=indexA)